# How to normalize this into 1NF/2NF?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I've been researching normalization and I'm not quite sure how to normalize this database?

Let's just say I have something like this:

```
Table: Movies

| MovieID | Title | Rating | StarID | Star                      |
| 1       | Blah  | R      | 1      | Joe Johnson               |
| 2       | Blah2 | R      | 1, 2   | Joe Johnson, John Johnson |
```

Would 1NF look like this or am I wrong?:

```
Table: Movies

| MovieID | Title | Rating |
| 1       | Blah  | R      |
| 2       | Blah2 | R      |

Table: Movies2
| Movie ID | StarID | Star          |
| 1        | 1      | Joe Johnson   |
| 2        | 2      | John Johnson  |
```

What would 2NF look like this for then (if I'm right)?

Comment: @James
[tblStars] StarID | Star  
[tblMovies] MovieID | Title | Rating

Movies2 is an Intermediary Table.

Comment: Hint for 2NF: What would that structure look like if the same person starred in two different movies? What duplicated data would you see? (I note that you actually _have_ that data now; you just didn't denormalize MovieID 2 correctly)

Comment: @JonStirling The _structure_ is correct but the _data_ is not - there should be two rows for MovieID 2.

Answer (score 1):

> a table is in 2NF if it is in 1NF and no non-prime attribute is
>   dependent on any proper subset of any candidate key of the table. A
>   non-prime attribute of a table is an attribute that is not a part of
>   any candidate key of the table.

The Movies and Movies2 are in 1NF (may be you want to change Movies2 to something like Movies-Stars or Starring etc)

Since you have composite primary/candidate keys for Movies2 table(MovieID and StarID), you will have to bother about 2nf. 
So you will have to move the **Star** in to it's own table (StarID and Star).

But if you want to go for 3NF then the condition for 3NF is -

> (1) the entity is in second normal form, and (2) all the attributes in a table are determined only by the candidate keys of that table and not by any non-prime attributes.

This condition is already satisfied when you decompose your data to meet 2NF as below-
1) Movies ( MovieID | Title | Rating )
2) Movies2 ( Movie ID | StarID ) and
3) Stars ( StarID | Star )

(since the above data also satisfies BCNF criteria ). For your given data,  (2NF)fully handles all the redundancies due functional dependencies.

References  - wikipedia (2nf and 3nf)

Comment: @James - "What would NF3 look like then?"  . 3NF deals with transitive dependencies. For the data you have, after doing 2NF you are not left with any transitive dependencies. So 2NF solves all the normalization required due to functional dependencies. Hope this answers.

Answer (score 1):

It's always strange not to normalize tables completely, but to think of the normal forms as different stages.

Anyway: The table violates NF 1, because data is not atomic (`1, 2` and `Joe Johnson, John Johnson`). You convert it to NF 1 by having more records instead of lists in columns:

```
| MovieID | Title | Rating | StarID | Star         |
| 1       | Blah  | R      | 1      | Joe Johnson  |
| 2       | Blah2 | R      | 1      | Joe Johnson  |
| 2       | Blah2 | R      | 2      | John Johnson |
```

A typical primary key for this table would be MovieID + StarID. (And the table name should not be Movie any longer, because a row doesn't represent one movie now, but one movie-actor pair.)

This table violates NF 2, because the Star column doesn't depend on both MovieID + StarID, but on StarID only.

This is a very strange example by the way, with MovieID and StarID being artificial IDs. Why would someone create a StarId, but put it in the Movie table? Looks very constructed. And it can be transformed to NF 2 easily by removing the redundant column:

```
| MovieID | Title | Rating | Star         |
| 1       | Blah  | R      | Joe Johnson  |
| 2       | Blah2 | R      | Joe Johnson  |
| 2       | Blah2 | R      | John Johnson |
```

Or keeping the ID and adding a Star table:

```
| MovieID | Title | Rating |StarID
| 1       | Blah  | R      |1
| 2       | Blah2 | R      |1
| 2       | Blah2 | R      |2

| StarID | Star         |
| 1      | Joe Johnson  |
| 2      | John Johnson |
```

Only, nobody would do that. You simply don't stop at NF 2.

Comment: What would NF3 look like then? O_o

Comment: It would remove the redundantly stored movie entries by making this three tables instead: `movie`, `star`, and a bridge table `movie_star` to represent this n:m relation.

Comment: "It's always strange not to normalize tables completely" - substitute 'pedagogic' for 'strange' i.e. it's what gets taught at college and the message, "Full normliation is always achievable and desirable" often seems to be lost. Normalization is a process to fix design flaws but most professionals quickly learn what fully normalized looks like and go straight there. Great answer, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need an actor table, too.

```
Table: Actor
| ActorID | Actor          |
| 1       | Joe Johnson    |
| 2       | John Johnson   |
```

Then, the movies2 table becomes:

```
Table: Movies2

| Movie ID | StarID | 
| 1        | 1      | 
| 2        | 2      |
```

This removes the redundant Actor info in movies2, and allows you to have multiple Stars for a movie, or the same actor stars in multiple movies without repeating the Actor name, which is not an attribute completely dependent on MovieID. StarID refers to the Actor table.